# What are the standard practices for hyphenating/spelling scientific words

Tags: phd, publications, thesis, language, writing-style

I would like to know what are standard practices when words are spelled differently across the literature and/or dictionaries (when these words can be found in dictionaries). A few examples of the kind of discrepancies I see:

```
  flow field vs flow-field vs flowfield
  sub-critical vs subcritical
  mass flow-rate vs mass-flow rate vs mass flowrate
  sub-grid vs subgrid
```

Is the most important thing for my own work (i.e., PhD thesis) to be consistent? For example, just make sure flow-field is always hyphenated?

Comment: Probably belongs on English Stack Exchange

Comment: @gerrit This is more an issue of *usage* within the domain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This depends upon what's being written. For a university thesis, for instance, you should follow the guidelines of your particular institution: if they recommend a particular style manual, such as the [*Chicago Manual of Style*](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html) or the [*ACS Style Guide*], then you should follow the recommendations contained therein. If you are publishing in another venue, follow the guidelines of the publisher, if they make those available.

Otherwise, you should follow a consistent set of guidelines. Note that this is *not* the same as saying "always use a hyphen" or "never use a hyphen." For instance, you would write

> "the velocity of the flow field increased"

but

> "the flow-field variables are . . ."

because "flow field" is a noun in the first example, and "flow-field" is an adjective in the second. There the hyphen links the connected words: "flow-field" and "variable" versus "flow" and "field variable."

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I had never looked into that subtlety before (English is not my mother tongue). Unfortunately, my university does not seem to recommend any specific style guide, so I will just try to follow the general principles you described and also the answer to this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68642/should-i-use-hyphens-with-prefixes-like-sub-and-semi) or this [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word).

Comment: Hyphenation can sometimes change the meaning. un-ionised vs union-ised.